# How to access content of Apple Push Notification by using MDM?

Tags: ios, swift, enterprise, mdm

I'm trying to find a way to access content of all push notifications through notification center.

In other words I want to know what my employees/kids have received from WhatApp and SnapChat etc.

I have done some R&D to see which port of apple receive the message or to see how smart watches access push notification.

**Has anyone done something similar or any hint or lead can be greatly appreciated?**

In Android there is an API to access notifications but not sure about iOS!!

Ports used by apple:
https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202944

Ports on APN
https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT203609

Access to push notifications through Bluetooth:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: You cannot access push notification content on iOS, even with an MDM.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to inform you that such a system is not possible in iOS . All iOS apps are sanboxed and data of one app cannot be read by another. Thats the reason you cant find any apps to read OTP password form message except the native keyboard app.

Apple will not allow any apps/service even in future as Apple devices are designed for more security and privacy. It violated basic privacy of end user and it should not be done.

Having said that , you can always control installing of apps  / removing app remotely etc through MDM . You can take more control of your employees devices through a MDM software .